# IndexError: list index out of range, even though my list is within the range I am inputting

Tags: python

I am new to python and I can't seem to get the [1] out of the [1] list. Here is my code.

```
boy_names = ['brendan ' 'john ' 'ben ' 'zach ' 'pete ' 'ralph']

girl_names = ['lauren ' 'makenna ' 'kayley ' 'mom ' 'olivia ' 'dingus']

names = [boy_names, girl_names]

print(names[1][1])
```

After running I am receiving this error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Typo.  You don't have any commas in either of your lists, so each one is a list containing one string.  `boy_names = ['brendan','john','ben','zach','pete','ralph']`.  Doing some simple debug prints would have shown you this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don`t have any commas in your lists: boy_names, girl_names. When you try to call first value of names[1] it gives you exception because Python sees you have only one value, so it fixes your problem:

```
boy_names = ['brendan ', 'john ', 'ben ', 'zach ', 'pete ', 'ralph']

girl_names = ['lauren ', 'makenna ', 'kayley ', 'mom ', 'olivia ', 'dingus']

names = [boy_names, girl_names]

print(names[1][1])
```

instead of:

```
boy_names = ['brendan ' 'john ' 'ben ' 'zach ' 'pete ' 'ralph']

girl_names = ['lauren ' 'makenna ' 'kayley ' 'mom ' 'olivia ' 'dingus']

names = [boy_names, girl_names]

print(names[1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python list is separated by,(Comma)
Eg: x = [a,b,c,d]

For your code, It is considered a single list. so [1] is out of range.

Here the correct syntax:

```
boy_names=['brendan','john','ben','zach','peter','ralph']

girl_names = ['lauren','makenna','kayley','mom', 'olivia','dingus']

print(boy_names[1],girl_names[1])
```